# Eclipse CDT: How to generate header file from source file?

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600

---

Hello,
is there a way to auto generate a header (.h) from functions in a source (.c) file (plus keeping it up to date)? May be even a vice versa generator?

Example:

test.c

```
void print_val(int val) {
    printf("Val: %i", val);
}

int add(int val1, int val2) {
    return (val1 + val2);
}
```

Now I want to generate automaticly an header file

foo.h

```
    /*
 * foo.h
 *
 *  Created on: 22.02.2019
 *     
 */

#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

    void print_val(int val);

    int add(int val1, int val2);

#endif /* FOO_H_ */
```

Also the header file should auto update if I change something in the function declaration (if I want, best with checkboxes what to update)...

Comment: Not sure about CDT, but normally header files are not derived from source files. What problem do you want to solve here?

Comment: There is an option to `"Implement Methods"`, if you have the header file and would like to have the (*empty*) definitions of the functions in source file, corresponding to the functions declared in the header file. BUT not the other way round as you are asking for.

Comment: If you have a big need for this feature, I would guess that there's something wrong with your general process. Generating an empty source file from a header file makes sense, and that feature exists.

Comment: *"Implement Methods"* does not work here also. I get an error: `No methods to implement found`

Comment: Normally you define all the macros, types, enums etc. in a header and only use it in the C file. This cannot be done automatically as this information is not present in the C file. Also you could have one header but split implementation in multiple C files

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a function that generates an empty `.c` from a `.h` file that is called "Implement Methods". The opposite does not exist in Eclipse, and for pretty good reasons.

Don't get me wrong. Sometimes you need to change a header file, but it would not necessarily be a good thing to do this automatically. At least not without some kind of directives. For instance, when you're coding tail recursive functions, it is very common to have an auxiliary function that should not be exposed. It could look something like this:

```
int sumArrayAux(int * array, size_t size, int currentSum) {
    if(size == 0) return 0;
    return sumArrayAux(array + 1, size - 1, *array);
}

int sumArray(int * array, size_t size) {
    return sumArrayAux(array, size, 0);
}
```

In general, you would not want to expose the first function. The function `sumArray` is intended to be the interface.

Another example is if you have data structures that are not meant to be fiddled with, except via the api. You could for instance have this:

```
struct Matrix {
    int * values;
    size_t cols, rows;
};
```

And some functions:

```
void matrixMultiply(Matrix * A, Matrix * B, Matrix *destination) {
    ...
}

size_t numberOfColumns(Matrix * m) { return M->cols; }
size_t numberOfRows(Matrix * m) { return M->rows; }
```

Then you would probably want a `.h` that looks like this:

```
typedef struct Matrix Matrix;
void matrixMultiply(Matrix * A, Matrix * B, Matrix *destination);
size_t numberOfColumns(Matrix * m);
size_t numberOfRows(Matrix * m);
```

But in other cases, for instance if `numberOfX` function does not exist, it could make more sense to expose the whole structure of `Matrix`.

The point is that the header file is supposed to be the interface, and you should not change an interface without a good reason and careful consideration. In the best of worlds you should be supposed to do whatever changes to the `.c` file without affecting any of the files that includes the `.h`.

Furthermore, it's not uncommon to have several `.c` files to implement one single `.h`. Also, you may have preprocessor macros defined that would complicate such an automatic translation.

Comment: Mainly I'd like to take the way from .c -> .h also of course the editor should ask if it should update and maybe show a selection. Also "Implement Methods" does not work. Even without a existing .c file...

Answer (score 0):

After seeing that it seems there is no functionality, I am doing it quick and dirty with a regular expression search and replace:

1. Close all other tabs
2. STRG + H
3. Choose File tab
4. In search field the regular expression: `(?m)(?s) \{.*?\R\}\R`
5. Click on "Resource in active editor"
6. Click Replace
7. Replace it with a semicolon `;`
8. Use preview to look at the changes (just in case)

May be there is something like a macro recorder for Eclipse out to do it with one click??

Answer (score 0):

When having to create headers for bad legacy code I followed [Tick Tac Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54829757/889871) with this addition:

If the code contains the opening curly **brackets on a new line**, this regex works:

```
(?s)\R\{\R.*?\R\}
regex-replace into:
;
```

If you have mixed code, use this pattern first, to possibly prevent wrong matches by Tick Tac Joe's pattern (due to `if`'s brackets).

(I cannot comment due to reputation)